# Flume cannot put files to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hadoop, amqp, flume

I'm using flume in its node-only (testing) mode; flume pulls messages from RabbitMQ and puts it to Amazon S3 bucket.

### The problem:

Flume actually pulls from RabbitMQ, but files do not appear at S3 bucket.

### Technical details:

I start flume in following manner:

```
flume node -1 -c $FQDN':amqp("exchangeName=[exchange name]", "bindings=[binding name]", "host=127.0.0.1", "port=5672", "userName=[user]", "password=[pass]", "exchangeType=direct", "durableExchange=false", "queueName=[queue name]", "durableQueue=true", "exclusiveQueue=false", "autoDeleteQueue=false", "useMessageTimestamp=true")|collectorSink("s3n://[Amazon key]:[Amazon secret]@[path at S3]","server");' -s "$@" > "$log" 2>&1
```

### Flume log:

After flume restart, when sending something through the relevant exchange and queue, the following lines appear in flume log:

```
INFO com.cloudera.flume.handlers.hdfs.EscapedCustomDfsSink: Opening s3n://[key]:[secret]@[path at S3]

WARN org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

WARN org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
```

Comment: Does Amazon have a log for S3 actions, can you turn the logging up to a higher level (Debug if possible) to see more detailed what's going wrong?

Comment: Yes, Amazon has S3 logging and it is turned on.

Comment: Nothing is suspecious there...

Comment: So are you actually seeing activity from Flume in those logs or does nothing appear there either because that would indicate it's not even connecting to S3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not believe it...

Flume just cannot manage with Amazon key containing '/'
The key I used contained one.
Then Flume recognized it and just did not called for Amazon.

Solution:
Change Amazon key till you get one without '/'